# PHP Image Compression then Upload

Tags: php, image, file-upload, compression

The following code I have is a combination from two sources.

Image Upload:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
Image Compression:https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-reduce-image-file-size-while-uploading-using-php-code/

The Image Upload feature uploads straight to the server. The compression one compresses the image then downloads it. I am trying to integrate this upload feature into my upload feature as it is already embedded in our website.

The following code does two things:

1. It compresses on upload and downloads
2. Uploads the raw image to the server uncompressed

What I want done is compress on upload and send to the server. I don't need it downloading. I am just having trouble integrating the two features together.

```
<?php 
    $name = ''; $type = ''; $size = ''; $error = ''; 
    function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) { 
        $info = getimagesize($source_url); 
        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); 
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url); 
        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url); 
        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality); 
        return $destination_url; 
    } 
if ($_POST) { 
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) { 
        $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"]; 
    } 
    else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || 
             ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
             ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || 
             ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) { 
        $url = 'destination .jpg'; 

        $filename = compress_image($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $url, 80); 
        $buffer = file_get_contents($url); 

        /* Force download dialog... */
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
        header("Content-Type: application/download");

        /* Don't allow caching... */ 
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 

        /* Set data type, size and filename */ 
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer)); 
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$url"); 

        /* Send our file... */ 
        echo $buffer; 
//**The following is the image upload to the server**********
$target_dir = "newuploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);{
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "";}
    }
}

    else { 
        $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png"; 
    } 
} 
?> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Php code compress the image</title> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
        <div class="message"> 
            <?php 
            if($_POST){ 
                if ($error) { 
            ?> 
            <label class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></label> 
            <?php 
                } 
            } 
            ?> 
        </div> 
        <fieldset class="well"> 
            <legend>Upload Image:</legend> 
            <form action="" name="myform" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                <ul> 
                    <li> 
                        <label>Upload:</label> 
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
                    </li> 
                    <li> 
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/> 
                    </li> 
                </ul> 
            </form> 
        </fieldset> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the section of code that throws that data back to the browser so remove

```
    $buffer = file_get_contents($url); 

    /* Force download dialog... */
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    /* Don't allow caching... */ 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 

    /* Set data type, size and filename */ 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer)); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$url"); 

    /* Send our file... */ 
    echo $buffer;
```

Comment: Thanks that takes care of the downloading. But the compression variable is different than the uploading one. How am I supposed to integrate the compression into the upload feature? Right now it will upload to the server uncompressed.

Comment: You cannot compress the file until it arrives on the server.

Comment: So you're saying this code will not work? If not can you suggest how I should do this?